# WPF MediaPlayer Tasks, Timers and MediaEnded

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am creating a game in WPF. To manage sounds I've created a AudioController, which will create MediaPlayers and manage playing, stopping, looping, pausing, etc. I have the base of it working. If i'm in a control, I can call

```
AudioController.Play("MySound");
```

And it will decide if it has a MediaPlayer for that sound already, if not it will create one.

A problem appears in the following situations:

```
Task.Run(() => { DoSomething(); AudioController.Play("MySound"); });
_timer_tick(object sender...) { AudioController.Play("MySound"); }
```

When using a Task my Sound will play properly, but the MediaEnded event never gets fired, causing me not to be able to manage the MediaPlayers properly.

With the Timer Tick, the Sound will play the first time, but never again, even though its using **a new MediaPlayer** and also never fires the MediaEnded event

I've tried Dispatching the calls, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.
I can only imagine the problems lies with the idea that the Play() call is being sent from a different thread.

```
public static void Play(string sound)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Publish called on Thread Id {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    if (!Application.Current.CheckAccess())
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Play(sound, TimeSpan.Zero), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
        return;
    }

    Play(sound, TimeSpan.Zero);                
}

private static void Play(string sound, TimeSpan position)
{
    //...some preemptive code that's just searching a list

    //reuse
    if (ap == null)
    {
        ap = new AudioPlayer(entry);
        _players.Add(ap);
    }

    ap.Play(position);
}
```

**Note**: AudioPlayer is a wrapper class around MediaPlayer so that I can add some additional properties such as `LastActive`, `IsLooping`, and handles replaying a sound by calling:

```
_player.Stop();
_player.Position = position;
_player.Play();
```

**Update**:

I just decided to run a different sound in the above scenario's and everything seems to work fine. The only difference between the audio's is that one is 40kb and the other 67kb. Could it be that the file is just so small MediaPlayer doesn't register the NaturalDuration and therefore assumes its 0 which stops the events from being triggered?